# Change version of APK

Tags: android, version, apk

I think it's clear what my problem is. I have my apk now on the androidversion 4.1.2, but my friend has 4.2.2. How can i compile the apk to this version? Also i need not only this two versiones, I need many more. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What IDE are you using  ??

Comment: You really **don't need** a different apk for each OS version. Your app is already compatible with the newer OS versions.

Comment: what? i dont understand anything :D

Comment: is anyone german? :D

Comment: Your app will work on 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In targetSdkVersion Set maximum sdk version. if you set 21 than your application will work still 21 api.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: thanks! but have i to download all the versiones in the sdk manager?

Comment: ya for that you have to download all necessary sdk platform from sdk manager